# How can I get this form to work and save the updated information?

Tags: python, django, forms, django-models, django-forms

I was successful at getting the form to appear on the modal which was an issue I had earlier, now I'm struggling to make this work. Any way to work my way around this?? Also I wanna check if method == 'POST' before checking if the form is valid but can't seem to find a solution..

views:

```
class ProfileDetailView(LoginRequiredMixin, DetailView):
    model = Profile
    template_name = 'network/profile.html'


    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        user = User.objects.get(username__iexact=self.request.user)
        profile = Profile.objects.get(user=user)
        form = ProfileModelForm(instance=profile)
        confirm = False
        rel_r = Relationship.objects.filter(sender=profile)
        rel_s = Relationship.objects.filter(receiver=profile)
        rel_receiver = []
        rel_sender = []
        for item in rel_r:
            rel_receiver.append(item.receiver.user)
        for item in rel_s:
            rel_sender.append(item.sender.user)


        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            confirm = True

        context["rel_receiver"] = rel_receiver
        context["rel_sender"] = rel_sender
        context["posts"] = self.get_object().get_all_authors_posts()
        context["len_posts"] = True if len(self.get_object().get_all_authors_posts()) > 0 else False
        context["form"] = form
        context["confirm"] = confirm
        context["profile"] = profile

        return context
```

Form:

```
class ProfileModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'bio', 'avatar')
```

Model:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=64, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=64, blank=True)
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=64, blank=True)
    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to='avatars', default='avatar.png')
    background = models.ImageField(upload_to='backgrounds', default='background.png')
    following = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='following', blank=True)
    bio = models.TextField(default="No Bio..")
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, blank=True)

    objects = ProfileManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.user.username}"

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("profile-view", kwargs={"slug": self.slug})
```

HTML:

```
{% extends "network/layout.html" %}
{% load static %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block title %}
    My Profile
{% endblock title %}

{% block body %}
<!--Modal-->
<div class="modal fade" id="profileModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title">Update Your Profile</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <img width="100px" src="{{profile.avatar.url}}">
        <form action="", method="POST", enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form">
          {% csrf_token %}
          {{form}}
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Update</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div>
  {% if confirm %}
    <div class="alert alert-info" role="alert">Your profile has been updated!</div>
  {% endif %}
</div>
  <div class="row py-5 px-4">
    <div class="col-md-5 mx-auto">
        <!-- Profile widget -->
        <div class="bg-white shadow rounded overflow-hidden">
            <div class="px-4 pt-0 pb-4 cover">
                <div class="media align-items-end profile-head">
                    <div class="profile mr-3"><img src="{{object.avatar.url}}" width="130" class="rounded mb-2 img-thumbnail"></div>
                    <div class="media-body mb-5 text-white">
                        <h4 class="mt-0 mb-3">{{profile.first_name}} {{profile.last_name}}</h4>
                        <p style="color: black;" class="small mb-4"> <i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt mr-2"></i>{{profile.country}}</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="bg-light p-5 d-flex justify-content-end text-center">
                <ul class="list-inline mb-0">
                    <li class="list-inline-item">
                        <h5 class="font-weight-bold mb-0 d-block">{{object.get_posts_num}}</h5><small class="text-muted"> <i class="fas fa-image mr-1"></i>Posts</small>
                    </li>
                    <li class="list-inline-item">
                        <h5 class="font-weight-bold mb-0 d-block">{{object.get_followers_num}}</h5><small class="text-muted"> <i class="fas fa-user mr-1"></i>Followers</small>
                    </li>
                    <li class="list-inline-item">
                        <h5 class="font-weight-bold mb-0 d-block">340</h5><small class="text-muted"> <i class="fas fa-user mr-1"></i>Following</small>
                    </li>
                    <li class="list-inline-item">
                        <h5 class="font-weight-bold mb-0 d-block">{{object.get_liked}}</h5><small class="text-muted"> <i class="fas fa-user mr-1"></i>Likes</small>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="ml-2">
              {% if object.user and object.user not in rel_receiver and object.user not in rel_sender %}
              <form action="{% url 'send-invite' %}" method="POST">
                  {% csrf_token %}
                  <input type="hidden" name="profile_pk" value={{object.pk}}>
                  <button type="submit" class=" btn btn-sm btn-success w-btn"><i class="bi-plus-lg"></i>&nbsp;Follow</button>
              </form>
              {% endif %}

              {% if object.user in rel_receiver and request.user not in object.following.all %}
                <button class="btn btn-sm disabled "><i class="bi-three-dots"></i>&nbsp;Waiting aprroval</button>
              {% endif %}

              {% if request.user in object.following.all %}
                <form action="{% url 'remove-friend' %}" method="POST">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <input type="hidden" name="profile_pk" value={{object.pk}}>
                    <button type="submit" class=" btn btn-sm btn-dark w-btn"><i class="bi-dash-lg"></i>&nbsp;Unfollow</button>
                </form>
              {% endif %}
            </div>
            <div class="px-4 py-3">
                <h5 class="mb-0">About</h5>
                <button class="btn btn-sm btn-secondary float-right" id="modal-btn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#profileModal">Edit Profile</button>

                <div class="p-4 rounded shadow-sm bg-light">
                    <p class="font-italic mb-0">{{profile.bio}}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="py-4 px-4">
                <div class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between mb-3">
                    <h5 class="mb-0">Recent posts</h5><a href="#" class="btn btn-link text-muted">Show all</a>
                </div>
                {% if len_posts %}
                  <div class="row">
                    {% for post in posts %}
                      <div class="col-lg-6 mb-2 pr-lg-1 fluid">
                        {% if post.picture %}
                          <img class="card-img-profile" src="{{post.picture.url}}">
                        {% endif %}
                        {{post.content}}
                      </div>
                    {% endfor %}
                    {% else %}
                      <h1>This user didn't post anything yet..</h1>
                    {% endif %}
                  </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you have tried this:

In your view you should write a function called post.

```
def post(self, request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = self.form(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
           *whatever you need to do after you've validated the from*
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate on how I would use that function, I tried to do it, I successfully change the info but when I click on update it gets stuck, I don't know how i would make it work to fully change the profile info then gets redirected to the profile-view with reverse_lazy maybe @ThomasLewin

Comment: Yeah you have to add a response to the post function, and if you want to add things that aren't in the form you use commit=false

```
if form.is_valid():
                    form_data = form.save(commit=False)                    
                    form_data.updated_by = user
return redirect(self.request.path_info) 
```

That's how i typically do it.